# Trying to open imap port but it appears filtered in the firewall

Tags: firewall, dovecot

I´m trying to configure a dovecot imap server but I´m having some problems with the imap port in my firewall.

I use the APF (advance policy firewall) for managing iptables on a centos server. I try to open the 143 port, but with every nmap, the port appears as "filtered", and I´m unable to connect to imap from the mail client.

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would test the port with telnet or ncat to make sure the firewall doesn't have something that blocks scans.

```
telnet imap-server-ip 143
```

If that doesn't work, post your iptables rules:

```
sudo iptables -L -v
```

Comment: argggh, your answer made me remember that we have our offices under a firewall with the imap port closed, so the problem was here, not in the remote servers... arghhh... thanks for all!